# Washer method: Find volume of solid revolved around x-axis

Tags: calculus

Let  $\mathbb{R} $ be the region between the graphs of $y=1$ and $y=\sin(x)$ from $x=0 $ to $x={\pi\over2}$. The volume of the solid obtained by revolving  $\mathbb{R} $ about the x-axis is given by.

I think it's $\pi\int_0^{\pi\over2}(1-\sin x)^2\mathrm dx $  but the answer key says a different answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume of a thin disc with radius $r$ and width $dx$ is $\pi r^2 dx$. The volume of a washer with outer radius $r_1$, inner radius $r_2$, and width $dx$ is the volume of the disc of radius $r_1$ minus the volume of the disc of radius $r_2$, which is $\pi (r_1^2 - r_2^2) dx$. So in your case it is $\pi (1^2 - \sin(x)^2) dx$. So integrate this expression from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.